# Not an answer but constructive

Tags: support, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/342275/692328) does not provide an answer to the Op, it points out possible errors in the OPs logic, but does not suggest a way forward.

I flagged the answer as "Not an answer" which was disputed by the user who supplied the answer. I can see value in the answer, and it has upvotes so obviously others see value in it too, but is it an answer?

Perhaps it was better suited to the original unedited question, but since the question has been edited, what now.

What is the correct course of action on answers like this?

Comment: Leave it and move on?  There are plenty of questions and answers in greater need of moderation.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit actually matters; answers aren't supposed to be used to address the OP. But it's from 2008 and has a score of 29. Also, when reviewing "Not an Answer" flags, the reviewers don't see the actual question. So the answer has to *clearly* not be an answer to **any possible question at all** for this flag to work.

Comment: Not sure if the advice not to flag link only answers as NAA is still accurate; from what I've read on Meta that's what people currently do with those.

Comment: @BSMP link only will only be successful if it literally reads *[here](http://google.com)*. The link label must NOT provide any context at all or be related to the question. So my example could be declined if the answer to the question is to use the `here` command, in which case it is an answer...

Comment: That's an answer.  Answers don't have to solve every problem the OP faces. That answer identifies a core issue with OP's code, which the OP doesn't seem to understand.  Also, keep in mind the date of the question/answer.  That's from *eight years ago*.  Trivia: there were no comments back then, so you'll find comment-like answers from that period.  There really isn't much of a need to moderate borderline stuff like that if it's over a few years old.  Save your efforts for egregious crap that's managed to hang on.

Answer (score 1):

When you, wrongly, flagged that answer as *Not An Answer* a review task for the Low Quality Queue was created (find it in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/342275/timeline)). When that task got presented to the reviewers, they all choose [Looks OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12928573). Had they chosen Delete they had destroyed value. The OP of the answer wasn't involved in declining your flag!

Luckily the flag and review system works.

As you can read in the duplicate [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) pointed out by [BSMP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4076315/bsmp) you're not supposed to flag answers that **TRY** to answer a question. Mostly gibberish, new questions and (short) comments can be successfully flagged and be deleted. You might also take the age and votes of the post into account. Think twice if you're about to cause havoc on a double digit scored answer. You might want to consult meta first.

Comment: Thanks rene. I have just misunderstood what the flag is for. Which is why I've asked this here, I can whole heatedly agree it is not a low quality response, hence the title of this question. I'll know for next time.